# Options for installing an AAV

Tags: plumbing

We live in an old house from the 1870s. Stone foundation, the actual exterior walls extend beyond the foundation cause the toilet has a 12” rough in and the toilet rough is pretty much in line with the foundation so forget about trying to run a vent pipe through the drywall.  The toilet drains through a elbow to another elbow to essentially clear the foundation then there is a 3’ section of 3” ABS to the horizontal pipe to our septic system. I do not know the existing vent layout but I suspect the upstairs bathroom is vented to a pipe under our bathtub upstairs (claw foot tub).

Everything drains fine except for the downstairs toilet so I want to add a AAV somewhere on the 3” drain pipe but it doesn’t look like I have a lot of options. I could snakes 1.5” pvc almost horizontal to where I could cut a hole in the floor and run pvc to above the sink.  This is how you’re supposed to run N AAV but because of the toilet drain there isn’t a lot of room to play with and the vent would almost have to have a horizontal length before it can go up.

Option 2 is to run it straight up from the 3” horizontal toilet drain and put the AAV just below the subfloor.   Basement is unfinished. If I remove the insulation below the subfloor o should be able to get the AAV over 4” from the drain as per instructions. But this is below the drains in the bathroom.  Since my basement is unfinished and it would be exposed, it would not be hard to monitor it or change it if it becomes bad.  (Studor mini vent).

What is the preferred approach here? I don’t think either is totally ideal and frankly the majority of the time the toilet drains ok but it does seem to have issues once or twice a month, enough for me to want to do something.

I’m wary of installing the AAV below the subfloor however it would have to be pretty backed up to get there I think.

Jay

Comment: https://www.lowes.com/pd/Studor-Air-Admittance-Valve-Recess-Box-with-Faceplate/1000679311

Comment: AAV’s normally need to be in an accessible location if the toilet is pulling the water out of the sink trap adding an AAV in a cabinet at the sink would help.

Comment: I don’t believe that is happening, I believe the pedestal sink (not in a cabinet) is vented via the second floor bathroom which shares a drain since, conveniently they are on top of one another.  What I’m trying to solve is the occasional slow drain of the toilet.  Sometimes when flushing and it could be all urine, the toilet won’t flush, ai

Comment: ….and air can be seen exiting the drain which leads me to think that I need a vent on the horizontal branch drain that runs into the building drain.  I am learning more plumbing terms as I go along so bear with me.   And if I’m correct, 4” above is as recommended by Studor.